# How to get JSON result from an API call using jQuery(or Javascript) in a non-Ajax way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to JS an jQuery. And I am trying to build a key-value map from an API call which returns an array of key-value pairs.

```
[{"key":"191","value":244}, ... , {"key":"920","value":130}]
```

I came up with this ajax code. But following code will need the map constructed from loadMap. How to change it to non-ajax way that the "followingFunction" runs after loadMap finishes>

```
var mp = {};
(function loadMap() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api?start_date=2014-10-01&end_date=2014-11-01',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(arr){
            var out = "";
            for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                mp[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
            }
        }
    }); 
}());

//followingFunction which needs the information from mp
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `followingFunction` in the `success` callback?

Comment: Thx for reply! I tried this but somehow doesn't work. And there are lots of stuff following, it seems ugly to put all those in success.

Comment: I was just wondering how to call a api the non-ajax way?

Comment: answer below - you can use the `async` flag. it is by default set to true - just set it to false and it will be a blocking call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two different ways.

1) Execute`followingFunction`at the end of your `success` callback:

```
var mp = {};
function loadMap() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api?start_date=2014-10-01&end_date=2014-11-01',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(arr){
            var out = "";
            for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                mp[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
            }
            followingFunction();
        }
    });
};
loadMap();
```

2) Set the `async` flag to `false` (by default this flag is `true`). This will result in blocking call with synchronous execution:

```
var mp = {};
function loadMap() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/xxx/api?start_date=2014-10-01&end_date=2014-11-01',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(arr){
            var out = "";
            for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                mp[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
            }
        }
    });
};
loadMap();
followingFunction();
```